# C# : how to build exe with ASP.NET Core 7.0 included

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, runtime

I have developed a C# console application that uses ASP.NET Core, and if I try to run it on a machine without that framework installed, I get a message that demands the corresponding aspnetcore-runtime.7.0 to be installed.

Since I would like to not require the user to install any runtimes, it would be nice if I could build a single EXE that internally brings all required runtimes, even if that increases the size of the EXE.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: If you have a **console** app - why do you have **ASP.NET Core** dependencies? ASP.NET Core is the **web stack** for .NET Core - a console app usually doesn't need that....

Comment: As suggested above, that does sound very strange. What exactly are you doing that (you think) requires ASP.NET Core? Maybe you only need the `System.Net` or `System.Web` libraries.

Comment: How about the self-contained when you are publishing the application? Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwxeO.png)